# Can I write a multithread Java program portable between pc and Android without modifying?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I need to write a small Java multithread program to utilise multi core. I want to run on both Windows and Android. But it seems Android uses something different from Java multithreading. Do I have to do two programs?

Comment: No experience with Android, but seems like normal Java to me: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code#java

Comment: Cannot access the link, blocked by the notorious chinese firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You don't have to write two different set of code for Windows and Android, provided you are talking about multi-threading portion of your code.

Of course you will need two different executable for Android and Windows as Android normally require your code to be compiled and packaged as APK file.

Regarding multi-threading, Android supports all Java standard library classes related to multi-threading. Android also provides few extra classes like AsyncTask etc. two abstract away complexities of multi-threading for an average Java programmer. But these android specific utility classes are implemeted on top of existing standard Java threading.

So a multi-threaded code written using standard java packages will work without modification on Android too.

The code below will work perfectly on both Android and Windows.

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    int a = 1000;
    a     = a * 200;
  }
}

Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
myThread.start();
myThread.join();
```

ForkJoinTasks too is supported in Android. See details here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask

Comment: Which means I can use fork/join?

Comment: @Chenxi You can definitely do join() on a thread. I am not sure about fork(). But I believe that it may not be possible.

Comment: @Chenxi If you are asking for ForkJoinTask, then it is supported in Android. See more details here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask